# how can I convert all of the pages from a website to pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, web

I need to make edits for a website developer / designer and he asked me to print all of the pages and make comments directly on them.

There are about 35 unique pages that I want to edit, although there are thousands that can be automatically generated from a database, but these are numbered sequentially. Thus, I would like to only download pages with an index of 1 in the address, e.g.,

It would be great if there were a bash solution that I could use, but Ruby would also work - the site is written in ruby, and the developer is good with ruby and bash and some other languages - so if you could give some suggestions to get us started, that would be great.

I want to print all pages in the server.com/ directory except, if the page is indexed by record, those with index > 1:

- server.com/records/
- server.com/records/1
- server.com/records/1/new

but not

- server.com/records/2
- server.com/records/2/new

or any pages with a ? in them like

- server.com/records?letter=K

and etc

Is there a simple, automated way that I could convert all of the pages to pdf?

Comment: Why not just do it manually? Open all the pages in tabs in your browser and print to pdf. It probably took you longer to ask your question here :)

Comment: thats what I did the first time ... and you are right that it will probably take me longer the second time, but another benefit would be the ability to incorporate the most recent snapshots of the pages in the database documentation file (automatically sourced from latex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I'd recommend good old [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/), but now there's [PDFkit](http://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) that can use your HTML+CSS as-is.

There are good Railcasts on both [PDFkit](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) and [Prawn](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article that can help you:
http://jimneath.org/2009/02/16/creating-pdf-documents-in-ruby-on-rails/
You can also look at: princely :)
https://github.com/drnic/princely

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is an excellent tool that works nicely in Ubuntu

```
 wkhtmltopdf www.google.com foo.pdf
 xpdf foo.pdf
```